# Rails - Elasticsearch - search by coordinates with Chewy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coordinates, chewy-gem

I'm using Elasticsearch on my Rails APP trhough `gem 'chewy'`.

I have two models: Products and Tags [many to many relationship, managed through ProductTag model].

I defined ProductsIndex as follow:

```
class ProductsIndex < Chewy::Index
  define_type Product do
    field :name
    field :tags, value: -> { tags.map(&:name)}
    field :coordinates, type: 'geo_point', value: ->{ {lat: lat, lon: lon} }
  end
end
```

I can successfully query ProductsIndex in my controller with:

```
q = params[:q]
@products = ProductsIndex.filter { tags(:and) == [q] }.load
```

which returns me all the Product objects with the specified tag.

My question is: How can I query ProductIndex to return all the Product objects within a radius of 100Km from a given pair of coordinates (lat/lon)?

I do not strictly need sorting by distance, but if you include it in your answer it will be greatly appreciated :)

## edit

I'm trying something like this but it doesn't work:

```
ProductsIndex.filter {
  geo_distance: {    
    distance: '100km',    
    location: {        
      lat: 60.0951482712848,        
      lon: -86.4810766234584    
    }
  }
}
```

I got the following syntax error

```
 SyntaxError: (irb):10: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'
...uctsIndex.filter {geo_distance: {    distance: '100km',    l...
...                               ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a wild hunt, and a long afternoon, but eventually the errors were pretty silly:

1. I was using `location` in the query while I defined `coordinates` as field type;
2. wrong brackets after `.filter`.

The correct syntax is as follow:

```
ProductsIndex.filter(geo_distance: {
  distance: "100km",
  coordinates: {
    lat: <latitude>,
    lon:<longitude>
  }
})
```

Hope it might help.